# Can I send tracking ID which is being generated for the shipment to PayPal?

Tags: paypal, shippo

Have a website where shippo is integrated. In checkout page I can select shipment options which are coming via shippo API. During checkout can I feed tracking ID proivided by shippo to PayPal?

It's needed for payment protection on PayPal. PayPal should have addresses submitted by user which I can pass to paypal but unable to send tracking ID, Looking for a solution on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

While Shippo will return the tracking number inside the transaction response, there currently does not appear to be any way to submit tracking information directly to the PayPal API.

For eBay related orders, there is the [SetShipmentTrackingInfo](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/merchant-data/CallRef/SetShipmentTrackingInfo.html) API which should fulfill the Seller requirements for tracking.

Paypal does appear to be aware of this request however [PayPal-REST-API-issues](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-REST-API-issues/issues/158).

Comment: Thank you you for your answer. I am in touch with PayPal and Shippo both to figure out the solution as moving forward.